# MySQL SELECT + LEFT JOIN + IF query

Tags: mysql, select, join, if-statement

I have one of simple DB tables named category:

```
category.id category.name category.lang
1           'apple'       'en'
1           'manzana'     'es'
1           ''            'de'
1           ''            'it'
```

Variable:

```
$default_lang = 'en';
$current_lang = 'it';
```

I would like to make query that returns category_name field according to $current_lang, but if category.name is empty then should use category.name from $default_lang like this:

```
SELECT * FROM cat_list
    LEFT JOIN category ON cal_list.id = category.id
          AND IF(category.name = $current_lang = '', $default_lang, 'No Lang')
```

Please let me know, how could i fix this query to make it work?

===

Ok now I have a good Idea:

```
SELECT * FROM cat_list LEFT JOIN category 
           ON cal_list.id = category.id 
          AND category_lang IN ($curreng_lang, $default_lang)
          AND category_name <> ''
```

it works fine but should I worry about the "IN" order in case if both languages has name values?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT catname=
CASE name
         WHEN '' THEN (select name from Category where lang=$default_lang limit 1)
         ELSE name
      END
FROM Category where id=$current_lang
```

Explaination:
here Query is using case statement inside select statment,
where
outer query is using condition "id=$current_lang"

so in select statement it will have name='', so for

```
catname=
    CASE name
             WHEN '' THEN (select name from Category where lang=$default_lang limit 1)
             ELSE name
          END
```

name is '', so first condition with when should execute
here it will execute query

> (select name from Category where lang=$default_lang limit 1)
>   name apple is returned (because language is 'en')
>   and that will be sotred to catname variable. which will be returned in result

If it will get value with something for name first time (id=$current_lang) it will return with it.

Comment: please elaborate more so user can understand more easily only code as answer is not a good way to answer

Comment: Patriks, it is possible to implement it without SELECT in SELECT? because table category has about 800,000 rows :(

Answer (score 2):

Is the `category.name` *NULL* or *empty string*?

If *NULL*, use `COALESCE` (*Returns the first non-NULL value in the list*)

```
SELECT category.id, 
       COALESCE(category.name, $default_lang) name,
       COALESCE(category.lang, $current_lang) lang
FROM cat_list
     LEFT JOIN category 
           ON cal_list.id = category.id
```

If *Empty String*, Use `IF`

```
SELECT category.id, 
       IF(category.name = '', $default_lang,category.name) name,
       IF(category.lang = '', $current_lang,category.lang) lang
FROM cat_list
     LEFT JOIN category 
           ON cal_list.id = category.id
```

Comment: I do use Empty String, but: IF(category.name = '', $default_lang,category.name) name, this will just return 'en' ($default_lang) for 'name' field in case of category.name <> '' ?

Comment: @user1664869 `category.name` will be display if it is not null or empty string.

Comment: Johnny, what do you think if to make it like this: SELECT * FROM cat_list LEFT JOIN category ON cal_list.id = category.id AND category_lang IN ($curreng_lang, $default_lang) ?

Comment: @user1664869 that will only show records that has language og `en` and `it` and nothing more.

Comment: yes, only two 2 row is ok one is current_lang another one is default_lang, but at the end I need to choose only one that category.name <> ''

Answer (score 0):

user1664869,
what about this?

```
SELECT catname=CASE c1.name
       WHEN '' THEN c2.name
       ELSE c1.name
       END
FROM
Category c1
INNER JOIN Category c2 ON c1.lang=$current_lang and c2.lang=$default_lang;
```